# Use npm packages workbox-core and workbox-routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, workbox

I try to figure out how to use [`workbox-core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-core) and [`workbox-routing`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-routing).

**Note** I use a gulp+browserify bundle to make my code work on my browser.

I downloaded the package using yarn:

```sh
yarn add --dev workbox-core@4.* workbox-routing@4.*
```

Which works fine. The service worker is correctly installed, and further reload will skip waiting.

Then I wrote this in my service worker:

```
import { workbox } from "workbox-core";

workbox.core.clientsClaim();
workbox.core.skipWaiting();
```

And then I tried to add routing:

```
import { workbox } from "workbox-core";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";

workbox.core.clientsClaim();
workbox.core.skipWaiting();
```

But I came up with this error in DevTools:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: workbox is not defined

So I guess at some point `workbox-routing` needs `workbox-core` to work because this is the involved code in the error stack trace:

```
e.setDefaultHandler=(e=>{u().setDefaultHandler(e)}),e}({},workbox.core._private,workbox.core._private)},{}],3:[function(e,t,r){"use strict";var n=e("workbox-core");e("workbox-routing");n.workbox&&(n.workbox.core.clientsClaim(),n.workbox.core.skipWaiting(),console.log("routing",n.workbox))},{"workbox-core":1,"workbox-routing":2}]},{},[3]);
```

**QUESTION**

How can I use workbox alongside its component (routing, strategies, ...) in node?

**WORKAROUND**

Here is what I actually do to come around this issue. I find this is not taking advantage of splitted components that workbox-* offer, but this has the merit to work...

```
import "workbox-sw";
import { workbox as workboxCore } from "workbox-core";

const routes = ["/", "/nous-trouver", "/mentions-legales", "/produit"];

const assetsStrategy = new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: "assets-v5"
});

// Main
workboxCore.core.clientsClaim();
workboxCore.core.skipWaiting();

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp(".*(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|webp|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$"),
    assetsStrategy
);

for (const route of routes) {
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(route, assetsStrategy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the guidance in this [Using Bundlers (webpack/Rollup) with Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-bundlers) guide?

I am not sure that Browserify is up to the task of following all of the dependencies when creating a custom bundle, and would suggest trying Rollup or webpack instead.